# save datasources equivalent in javascript server side syntax

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I'm looking for the equivalent of the simple action "save Datasources" in javascript server side syntax.
I already know how to perform a save for a single datasource but not for more than one.
For example, if you have a repeat control that displays one document per entry, how to save all of them through a jss code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I use in my application to save all the members of a repeat:

```
<xp:button
    value="Save for Later"
    id="buttonSave"
    style="margin: 0px 20px"
    styleClass="redbutton_horz save">                   
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="partial"
        disableValidators="true">
        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var doc=document1.getDocument();
doc.replaceItemValue("aStatus","Incomplete");    

save();  //save all data sources
context.redirectToPage("home.xsp");}]]></xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Not sure how you intend to use it, but likely all you would need is the save(); method shown in the example code above.

Comment: Excellent ! it works as I expected. 
Is there any documentation about simple actions and their related equivalent in JSS syntax ?

Comment: This online reference has a section for Simple Actions; http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/SSVRGU_9.0.1/com.ibm.designer.domino.api.doc/r_wpdr_simpleactions_r.html?cp=SSVRGU_9.0.1